# How to choose option amount record user in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, backend

> I'm try to create choose option with 500 users

> This my Controller

```php
public function index()
    {
        $request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
    
     $employees = Employee::select('name','phone','email','id', DB::raw('2020 - year(day_of_birth) as age'));
     $amount = $request->record; 
     dd($amount);// output is null
     if( $amount == '25') $employees= $employees->paginate(25);
     else if($amount == '50') $employees= $employees->paginate(50);
     else if($amount == '100') $employees= $employees->paginate(100);
     else if($amount == '250') $employees= $employees->paginate(250);
     else $employees= $employees->paginate(500);
     return view('employees.index',['employees'=>$employees]);
    }
```

> This is index.blade.php

```
...
<div class="clearfix">

        <form class="title_left form-inline row" method="get" action="{{route('search')}}">
          
...        
</form>
        <div class="custom-select">
          <select name="record" class="custom-select">
            <option value="25" selected="selected">25</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="250">250</option>
            <option value="500">500</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
...
```

> When i loading route index it's always has 500 users.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests

Comment: $name = $request->input('name');

Comment: i'm changed  $record = $request->input('record'), but  it's always output null

Comment: Show us more HTML code. I do not see a `form`

Comment: i  edited my post, check it please!!

Comment: my select tag not in form

Comment: 0_o what do you mean "not in form? Only form data will go to the server side. Of course you can use some kind of JS magic. Then show us.

Comment: wrap your `select` tag with `form` tag

Answer (score 0):

This occur when your all conditions are failed then else portion executed.
Where you've set 500;

```
     else $employees= $employees->paginate(500);
```

get option value please use this

$request->input('option_field_name');

Comment: i'm changed $record = $request->input('record'), but it's always output null

Comment: please check first your $request parameter. You're getting the value or not.